# CMake Assembling Files Twice

Tags: assembly, cmake, x86, ninja

I'm trying to use CMake to compile a simple bootloader, if you could even call it that, but it seems to be trying to assemble my assembly files twice, rather than assemble it and objcopy the output to the final binary.

This is my CMakeLists for the bootloader:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.3.2)

PROJECT(bootloader ASM_NASM)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(bootloader 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/arch/${ARCH}/boot.asm
)
```

The output of the build shows that it's assembling the .asm file, and then also assembling the .obj produced by the first assembly, which of course causes problems:

```
[1/2] /usr/bin/nasm    -MD bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj.d -MT bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj -f bin -o bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj bootloader/arch/x86_64/boot.asm
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/nasm   bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj -o bootloader/bootloader   && :
bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj:1: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
bootloader/CMakeFiles/bootloader.dir/arch/x86_64/boot.asm.obj:509: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
```

The first assembly pass works as expected - It is the expected 512 bytes, and I can use `boot.asm.obj` as a disk image in QEMU and boot it. However, the build assembles it again to try and put it into the `bootloader` binary, which prints the warnings and gives me a filesize of zero. It seems like it should be using `objcopy` to get the assembly into the binary, but instead it's trying to assemble it a second time.

Anyone have any ideas why CMake would have the .asm get assembled twice instead of assembling it and objcopying it to the output?

Comment: "However, the build assembles it again to try and put it into the bootloader binary, which prints the warnings and gives me a filesize of zero." It's not assembling it _again_, it's trying to link it. For something as custom as a bootloader, you might get further writing a custom command + target.

Comment: Alternately, you can play with the undocumented `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE` variable which uses an internal / undocumented "rule" format for specifying the linker command.